# Navigation from user control in win 7 phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am not able to call the navigation service from the user control.
even when I create one event handler on the main page to call the navigation service that is laos not working.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please show some code you're using, and explain what is not working - is an Exception being thrown?  Is it just not navigating silently?

Answer (score 7):

I think I see the problem, but like Austin indicated, there isn't much to go on in your initial description.  It sounds like you are trying to access the NavgationService (which is a [PhoneApplicationPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage(v=VS.92).aspx) property) from within a UserControl that you are placing on that page.

As with many things in these APIs, you have a couple of options.  First, you can access the [PhoneApplicationFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe(VS.92).aspx) (which contains your pages and manages navigation) and use it for navigation:

```
var frame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
frame.Navigate(new Uri("/TargetPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Alternatively, you can walk the control's Visual Tree using the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=VS.95).aspx) until you get to the containing page:

```
var page = GetParentOfType<PhoneApplicationPage>(this); // this is your user control


private static T GetParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject item) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    T result;
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    if (parent == null) return null;
    else if (parent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))
    {
          result = (T)parent;
    }
    else result = GetParameterOfType<T>(parent);
    return result;
}
```

As you see, the VisualTree approach involves more code, but gets you the containing page object, where you have more access to things like [NavigationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext(v=VS.92).aspx), etc.

Hope that was your question (and your answer.)

Comment: 3 Years old and still this helped me a lot :) Thank You!